Trying to unrar specific files within a specific directory
I have a bash script that extracts files from a .rar file.  I want to extract only *.foo and mydirectory/*.bar.  I followed Unrar specific files using wildcards to get at the first group of files, but that doesn't work for second.  I tried using unrar -x blah.rar mydirectory/\*.bar (and just *), which got me nothing and unrar -x blah.rar mydirectory which just got me an empty directory named mydirectory/.  Omitting the trailing slash got me nothing.

You could always use bsdtar instead of unrar.

Thanks.  bsdtar works much better.
